# Movieplayer doenst rotate anymore when I used setControlStyleNone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, movieplayer

I added this to my code when im initializing the movie

[m_pMPmpc.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

where m_pMPmpc is an MPMoviePlayerViewController

It worked fine but then I noticed that the movie doesnt rotate anymore while playing(but the app after the movie still rotates) but it detects the orientation at the start and follows that.

I need to set it to follow the landscape orientations while playing. Any idea on what code to add?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class child of MPMoviePlayerViewController and overriding the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to return yes when orientation is landscape. Instance your class instead the default MPMoviePlayerViewController.

It works for me.